# Test vectors for bitcoin core (blocks and transactions) needed

Tags: bitcoin-core, testnet, non-standard-transaction

I am looking for test vectors to test edge cases of an implementation. For instance:

- "Unusual" blocks that made it to the blockchain
- Non standard transactions that made it to the blockchain

Anything else that will help in testing the implementation. I have already obtained test vectors for secp256k1, so those are not needed. (If anyone needs them please comment below).

Comment: Block 501726? (Block reward)

Comment: @MCCCS good one. Any other examples?